# Issues getting rails-slim to render a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I am trying to get two links to render side by side such as:
amazon/chegg or something to that affect. I know how I can do this in html but I am having the hardest time to get this to work in rails slim. I was trying to use something along the lines of this:

```
a href="#{@group.amazon_link}" title="Amazon"
                    | /awesome-book
```

But it shows up like this

```
Where to buy: a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672324539" rel="nofollow noreferrer" title="Amazon" | /awesome-book
```

I did not get the second link implemented at all but that is because I cannot get the first one to show up as a clickable link. I have looked at the slim documentation but I did not find it too helpful. What is the syntax I should be using?

Comment: which html do you want to get?

Comment: The correction you've made makes things confusing. This is how it is rendering on the page (its not using a as a link but ouputting everything): Where to buy: a href="http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Java-Edition/dp/0672324539" title="Amazon" | /awesome-book

Comment: fixed, but the question is stay anyway

Comment: The html I want to get is Where to buy: amazon/other where the two are clickable links but it is not rendering my a tag as a clickable link and is instead just outputting that whole line

Answer (score 0):

May be [slim-lang](/questions/tagged/slim-lang) code will be like this:

```
a href=@group.amazon_link
= '/'
a href='/awesome-book'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `|` character with same indentation as the previous line, which will render the items next to each other (instead of as children).

```
a href='some_link' title='Amazon' amazon
| /
a href='some_other_link' awesome-book
```